# Find bonus of given empid using function in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, cursor

- But here i want bonus as 100 and i am getting 24000. I have tried
  without cursor but then i am getting nothing in the bonus only
  employee id i can see. As the program compiles without error. Are
  there unnecessary things that i should remove it will be helpful

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bonuss  
         (emp_id   IN   NUMBER)
          RETURN NUMBER 
        AS 
          SAL employees.salary%TYPE;
          commis employees.commission_pct%TYPE;
          Annualsalary NUMBER;
          bonus NUMBER;
          cursor x IS
          SELECT salary, commission_pct FROM employees for update of salary;
      BEGIN
      open x;
       loop 
        fetch x into sal, commis;
        exit when x%notfound;
          if commis is null then
              if Annualsalary <= 10000 then 
              bonus := 500;
              elsif Annualsalary > 10000 then 
              bonus := 100;  
              else bonus := 0;
              end if;
          else
              if Annualsalary <= 10000 then 
              bonus := 500;
              elsif Annualsalary > 10000 then 
              bonus := 100;  
              else bonus := 0;
              end if;
          end if;
            Annualsalary := sal * ( 1 + NVL (commis, 0) ); 
          RETURN Annualsalary;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('total income of each emp: ' || sal ||',The bonus is ' || bonus);
      end loop;
      close x;
      END bonuss;
      /

      Declare 
         emp_bonus       number;
         employee_no     number;

       BEGIN
           employee_no :=  205;
           emp_bonus   :=  bonuss (employee_no);
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Employee with ID ' || employee_no ||
           ' will get bonus ' ||emp_bonus) ;
      END;
      /  
  Output:

  Function BONUSS dropped.


  Function BONUSS compiled

  Employee with ID 205 will get bonus 24000


  PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
  ```

Comment: It's worked??? Please complete your question, any say your error, problem... we don't have data for this plan, you can edit post and add create table and insert sample data. and say you work with oracel or microsoft... you choose sql-server(microsoft) and plsql(oracle)

Comment: I removed the Microsoft SQL Server tag and added Oracle since that's the DBMS you are apparently using. Take care to specify the proper DBMS tag so that answers are appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I see lots of potential errors, some related to your problem, and some not.

First, the actual cause of your error is that your cursor does not filter on employee id. So you are accumulating for all employees.

Next, you  should not be doing SELECT ... FOR UPDATE, in a function.  The purpose of a function is to return a value. Period. Full stop.  It should not be anticipating an update.

Next, you keep comparing Annualsalary to some fixed value, but I see nowhere in the code where you assign a value to Annualsalary.

Beyond those technical errors, if I were writing this, I'd make several 'style' changes.

First, there's no point in writing mixed-case code in oracle.  While there is nothing technically wrong with it, it's like speaking English (oracle) with a strong French (Microsoft) accent.  Within the oracle world, Instead of mixed-case ("CamelCase") we tend to use all lower-case, with underscores. For example, instead of something like 'EmployeeName', we'd use 'employee_name'.

Next, in your variable declaration, I'd strongly recommend standardizing some prefixes to indicate the variable type:  'p_' for parms, 'v_' for variables, 'c_' for constants.  That way, when you see there references in lengthy code, it will remain obvious what item is.  To modify your code to this standard:

```
create or replace function bonuss  
       (p_emp_id   in number)
        return number 
      as 
        v_sal employees.salary%type;
        v_commis employees.commission_pct%type;
        v_annual_salary number;
        v_bonus number;
```

Next, if I were to use an explicit cursor (I wouldn't) I'd give it a meaningful name, that also indicates (for future reference) that it is a cursor:

```
cursor csr_emp IS
```

But I wouldn't use an explicit cursor at all.  I'd use a 'cursor for loop':

```
begin
  for x in (select salary, 
                   commission_pct 
            from employees
            where emp_id  = p_emid  '<<---- important to your case!)
)
    if x.commission_pct is null 
    <rest of code>
  loop;
end;
```

But since it appears that you want the function to return the bonus for a single employee (else, why is the emp_id an input parm?) you don't even need a cursor at all.

Comment: And if the OP is going to use camelCase, it should be `annualSalary` not `Annualsalary` anyway. (Not to mention `sal` not `SAL` etc. Just sticking to one style would be something.)

Comment: Also, there are mulitple references to the same hard-coded values ('if Annualsalary <= 10000').  Suppose that next year management decides the cutoff point for bonus is 5000.  Instead of having to locate multiple occurrences of that, just declare a constant (c_bonus_limit number := 10000) and reference that in the query.